# dojo non-modal dialog

Tags: dojo, dialog, non-modal

Is there a way to create a non-modal dialog window using dojo?  jQuery UI supports both modal and non-modal dialog boxes.  I am trying to convert a SilverLight application to HTML/javascript and finding it difficult to create non-modal windows using dojo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you might try [dojox.layout.FloatingPane](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/layout/FloatingPane.html)

Comment: Is it possible to remove the minimize function from floating pane?

Comment: You can try setting the 'dockable' parameter to false. From the docs- `dockable - Allow minimizing of pane if true` (http://dojotoolkit.org/api/dojox/layout/FloatingPane)

Comment: I could not make this widget use the selected theme.  It needs its own css.  Also to avoid the window being destroyed on close, you need to create your own widget as this is not supported.

Comment: Just for sure that you know. `dojox.layout.FloatingPane` is an **experimental** (1.9) floating window. It's not bad but be aware that styles are not included in the main Dojo/theme stylesheets because of the experimental status of the widget and other limitations. So you need to tune the widget any way

Answer (score 22):

You can set the display of the underlay to 'none', and you will have a non-modal Dialog. To do that, set the class of the Dialog to 'nonModal' (that's just a convention I'm creating right now), and in the CSS for the page, have an entry for .nonModal_underlay.

```
require(['dijit/form/Button','dijit/Dialog'],
  function (Button, Dialog) {
    var d = new Dialog({
                    'title':'I am nonmodal',
                    'class':'nonModal'
                  });
  });
```

---

```
.nonModal_underlay {
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: +1..does not affect any other instances of Dialog and it really works!!

Comment: This is indeed the function I was aiming for.  However, I don't understand how or why it works?  How do we get from adding a class called "nonModal" to the dialog to the style name "nonModal_underlay"?

Comment: When you create a Dojo dialog with class "whatever", Dojo also creates an underlay with corresponding class name "whatever_underlay". See http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/Dialog.html#coloring-the-underlay

The CSS I provided turns off the underlay entirely.

Comment: Works with other instances of `Dialog` but if you have multiple instances showing and try to do something with a `TooltipDialog` such as hiding showing your dialogs through a DropDownButton you will get weird behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Just add this in your css

```
.dijitDialogUnderlayWrapper{
    display:none !important
}
```

Comment: It would be more useful to developers who are new to Dojo if you explained why and how this works.

Comment: Dojo dialog is a dijit based widget which uses its own css. If we look at the css for modal dialog it uses div with  class "dijitDialogUnderlayWrapper". To make it non-modal ,it is only required to hide this div.

Answer (score 0):

For people that need truly modeless Dialog, Roy J provides only partial solution as the focus still is held within the Dialog. To fix this, you can copy the dijit/Dialog.js and its dijit/templates/Dialog.html to your own folder structure and rename them to ModelessDialog. Then remove the focus handler, the key handler and the underlay. Here is the full result:

```
define([
    "require",
    "dojo/_base/array", // array.forEach array.indexOf array.map
    "dojo/aspect",
    "dojo/_base/declare", // declare
    "dojo/Deferred", // Deferred
    "dojo/dom", // dom.isDescendant
    "dojo/dom-class", // domClass.add domClass.contains
    "dojo/dom-geometry", // domGeometry.position
    "dojo/dom-style", // domStyle.set
    "dojo/_base/fx", // fx.fadeIn fx.fadeOut
    "dojo/i18n", // i18n.getLocalization
    "dojo/keys",
    "dojo/_base/lang", // lang.mixin lang.hitch
    "dojo/on",
    "dojo/ready",
    "dojo/sniff", // has("ie") has("opera") has("dijit-legacy-requires")
    "dojo/window", // winUtils.getBox, winUtils.get
    "dojo/dnd/Moveable", // Moveable
    "dojo/dnd/TimedMoveable", // TimedMoveable
    "dijit/focus",
    "dijit/_base/manager", // manager.defaultDuration
    "dijit/_Widget",
    "dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
    "dijit/_CssStateMixin",
    "dijit/form/_FormMixin",
    "dijit/_DialogMixin",
    "dijit/layout/ContentPane",
    "dijit/layout/utils",
    "dojo/text!./templates/ModelessDialog.html",
    "dijit/a11yclick",  // template uses ondijitclick
    "dojo/i18n!dijit/nls/common"
], function(require, array, aspect, declare, Deferred,
            dom, domClass, domGeometry, domStyle, fx, i18n, keys, lang, on, ready, has, winUtils,
            Moveable, TimedMoveable, focus, manager, _Widget, _TemplatedMixin, _CssStateMixin, _FormMixin, _DialogMixin,
            ContentPane, utils, template){

    // module:
    //      company/common/ModelessDialog

    var resolvedDeferred = new Deferred(), _DialogBase, ds = null, DialogLevelManager = null, ModelessDialog,
       _currentDialog = null;
    resolvedDeferred.resolve(true);

    _DialogBase = declare("dijit._DialogBase" + (has("dojo-bidi") ? "_NoBidi" : ""),
                           [_TemplatedMixin, _FormMixin, _DialogMixin, _CssStateMixin], {
        templateString: template,

        baseClass: "dijitDialog",

        cssStateNodes: {
            closeButtonNode: "dijitDialogCloseIcon"
        },

        // Map widget attributes to DOMNode attributes.
        _setTitleAttr: { node: "titleNode", type: "innerHTML" },

        // open: [readonly] Boolean
        //      True if ModelessDialog is currently displayed on screen.
        open: false,

        // duration: Integer
        //      The time in milliseconds it takes the dialog to fade in and out
        duration: manager.defaultDuration,

        // refocus: Boolean
        //      A Toggle to modify the default focus behavior of a ModelessDialog, which
        //      is to re-focus the element which had focus before being opened.
        //      False will disable refocusing. Default: true
        refocus: true,

        // autofocus: Boolean
        //      A Toggle to modify the default focus behavior of a ModelessDialog, which
        //      is to focus on the first dialog element after opening the dialog.
        //      False will disable autofocusing. Default: true
        autofocus: true,

        // _firstFocusItem: [private readonly] DomNode
        //      The pointer to the first focusable node in the dialog.
        //      Set by `dijit/_DialogMixin._getFocusItems()`.
        _firstFocusItem: null,

        // _lastFocusItem: [private readonly] DomNode
        //      The pointer to which node has focus prior to our dialog.
        //      Set by `dijit/_DialogMixin._getFocusItems()`.
        _lastFocusItem: null,

        // draggable: Boolean
        //      Toggles the movable aspect of the ModelessDialog. If true, ModelessDialog
        //      can be dragged by it's title. If false it will remain centered
        //      in the viewport.
        draggable: true,
        _setDraggableAttr: function(/*Boolean*/ val){
            // Avoid _WidgetBase behavior of copying draggable attribute to this.domNode,
            // as that prevents text select on modern browsers (#14452)
            this._set("draggable", val);
        },

        // maxRatio: Number
        //      Maximum size to allow the dialog to expand to, relative to viewport size
        maxRatio: 0.8,

        // closable: Boolean
        //      ModelessDialog show [x] icon to close itself, and ESC key will close the dialog.
        closable: true,
        _setClosableAttr: function(val){
            this.closeButtonNode.style.display = val ? "" : "none";
            this._set("closable", val);
        },

        postMixInProperties: function(){
            var _nlsResources = i18n.getLocalization("dijit", "common");
            lang.mixin(this, _nlsResources);
            this.inherited(arguments);
        },

        postCreate: function(){
            domStyle.set(this.domNode, {
                display: "none",
                position: "absolute"
            });
            this.ownerDocumentBody.appendChild(this.domNode);

            this.inherited(arguments);

            aspect.after(this, "onExecute", lang.hitch(this, "hide"), true);
            aspect.after(this, "onCancel", lang.hitch(this, "hide"), true);

            this._modalconnects = [];
        },

        onLoad: function(){
            // summary:
            //      Called when data has been loaded from an href.
            //      Unlike most other callbacks, this function can be connected to (via `dojo.connect`)
            //      but should *not* be overridden.
            // tags:
            //      callback

            // when href is specified we need to reposition the dialog after the data is loaded
            // and find the focusable elements
            this.resize();
            this._position();

            if(this.autofocus && DialogLevelManager.isTop(this)){
                this._getFocusItems();
                focus.focus(this._firstFocusItem);
            }

            this.inherited(arguments);
        },

        focus: function(){
            this._getFocusItems();
            focus.focus(this._firstFocusItem);
        },

        _endDrag: function(){
            // summary:
            //      Called after dragging the ModelessDialog. Saves the position of the dialog in the viewport,
            //      and also adjust position to be fully within the viewport, so user doesn't lose access to handle
            var nodePosition = domGeometry.position(this.domNode),
                viewport = winUtils.getBox(this.ownerDocument);
            nodePosition.y = Math.min(Math.max(nodePosition.y, 0), (viewport.h - nodePosition.h));
            nodePosition.x = Math.min(Math.max(nodePosition.x, 0), (viewport.w - nodePosition.w));
            this._relativePosition = nodePosition;
            this._position();
        },

        _setup: function(){
            // summary:
            //      Stuff we need to do before showing the ModelessDialog for the first
            //      time (but we defer it until right beforehand, for
            //      performance reasons).
            // tags:
            //      private

            var node = this.domNode;

            if(this.titleBar && this.draggable){
                // prevent overload, see #5285
                if(has("ie") == 6) {
                    this._moveable = new TimedMoveable(node, { handle: this.titleBar });
                } else {
                    this._moveable = new Moveable(node, { handle: this.titleBar });
                }
                aspect.after(this._moveable, "onMoveStop", lang.hitch(this, "_endDrag"), true);
            }else{
                domClass.add(node, "dijitDialogFixed");
            }
        },

        _size: function(){
            // TODO: remove for 2.0
            this.resize();
        },

        _position: function(){
            // summary:
            //      Position the dialog in the viewport.  If no relative offset
            //      in the viewport has been determined (by dragging, for instance),
            //      center the dialog.  Otherwise, use the ModelessDialog's stored relative offset,
            //      adjusted by the viewport's scroll.
            if(!domClass.contains(this.ownerDocumentBody, "dojoMove")){    // don't do anything if called during auto-scroll
                var node = this.domNode,
                    viewport = winUtils.getBox(this.ownerDocument),
                    p = this._relativePosition,
                    bb = p ? null : domGeometry.position(node),
                    l = Math.floor(viewport.l + (p ? p.x : (viewport.w - bb.w) / 2)),
                    t = Math.floor(viewport.t + (p ? p.y : (viewport.h - bb.h) / 2))
                    ;
                domStyle.set(node, {
                    left: l + "px",
                    top: t + "px"
                });
            }
        },
        show: function(){
            // summary:
            //      Display the dialog
            // returns: dojo/promise/Promise
            //      Promise object that resolves when the display animation is complete

            if(this.open){
                return resolvedDeferred.promise;
            }
            if(_currentDialog && _currentDialog != this) {
                _currentDialog.destroy();
            }
            _currentDialog = this;
            if(!this._started){
                this.startup();
            }

            // first time we show the dialog, there's some initialization stuff to do
            if(!this._alreadyInitialized){
                this._setup();
                this._alreadyInitialized = true;
            }

            if(this._fadeOutDeferred){
                // There's a hide() operation in progress, so cancel it, but still call DialogLevelManager.hide()
                // as though the hide() completed, in preparation for the DialogLevelManager.show() call below.
                this._fadeOutDeferred.cancel();
                DialogLevelManager.hide(this);
            }

            // Recenter ModelessDialog if user scrolls browser.  Connecting to document doesn't work on IE, need to use window.
            // Be sure that event object doesn't get passed to resize() method, because it's expecting an optional
            // {w: ..., h:...} arg.
            var win = winUtils.get(this.ownerDocument),
                 // fade-in Animation object, setup below
                 fadeIn = null, promise;
            this._modalconnects.push(on(win, "scroll", lang.hitch(this, "resize", null)));

            //this._modalconnects.push(on(this.domNode, "keydown", lang.hitch(this, "_onKey")));

            domStyle.set(this.domNode, {
                opacity: 0,
                display: ""
            });

            this._set("open", true);
            this._onShow(); // lazy load trigger

            this.resize();
            this._position();

            this._fadeInDeferred = new Deferred(lang.hitch(this, function(){
                fadeIn.stop();
                delete this._fadeInDeferred;
            }));

            // If delay is 0, code below will delete this._fadeInDeferred instantly, so grab promise while we can.
            promise = this._fadeInDeferred.promise;

            fadeIn = fx.fadeIn({
                node: this.domNode,
                duration: this.duration,
                beforeBegin: lang.hitch(this, function(){
                    DialogLevelManager.show(this/*, this.underlayAttrs*/);
                }),
                onEnd: lang.hitch(this, function(){
                    if(this.autofocus && DialogLevelManager.isTop(this)){
                        // find focusable items each time dialog is shown since if dialog contains a widget the
                        // first focusable items can change
                        this._getFocusItems();
                        focus.focus(this._firstFocusItem);
                    }
                    this._fadeInDeferred.resolve(true);
                    delete this._fadeInDeferred;
                })
            }).play();

            return promise;
        },

        hide: function(){
            // summary:
            //      Hide the dialog
            // returns: dojo/promise/Promise
            //      Promise object that resolves when the display animation is complete

            // If we haven't been initialized yet then we aren't showing and we can just return.
            // Likewise if we are already hidden, or are currently fading out.
            _currentDialog = null;
            if(!this._alreadyInitialized || !this.open){
                return resolvedDeferred.promise;
            }
            if(this._fadeInDeferred){
                this._fadeInDeferred.cancel();
            }

            // fade-in Animation object, setup below
            var fadeOut = null, promise, h = null;

            this._fadeOutDeferred = new Deferred(lang.hitch(this, function(){
                fadeOut.stop();
                delete this._fadeOutDeferred;
            }));

            // fire onHide when the promise resolves.
            this._fadeOutDeferred.then(lang.hitch(this, 'onHide'));

            // If delay is 0, code below will delete this._fadeOutDeferred instantly, so grab promise while we can.
            promise = this._fadeOutDeferred.promise;
            fadeOut = fx.fadeOut({
                node: this.domNode,
                duration: this.duration,
                onEnd: lang.hitch(this, function(){
                    this.domNode.style.display = "none";
                    DialogLevelManager.hide(this);
                    this._fadeOutDeferred.resolve(true);
                    delete this._fadeOutDeferred;
                })
            }).play();

            if(this._scrollConnected){
                this._scrollConnected = false;
            }
            while(h = this._modalconnects.pop()){
                h.remove();
            }

            if(this._relativePosition){
                delete this._relativePosition;
            }
            this._set("open", false);

            return promise;
        },

        resize: function(dim){
            // summary:
            //      Called with no argument when viewport scrolled or viewport size changed.  Adjusts ModelessDialog as
            //      necessary to keep it visible.
            //
            //      Can also be called with an argument (by dojox/layout/ResizeHandle etc.) to explicitly set the
            //      size of the dialog.
            // dim: Object?
            //      Optional dimension object like {w: 200, h: 300}

            if(this.domNode.style.display != "none"){

                this._checkIfSingleChild();

                if(!dim){
                    if(this._shrunk){
                        // If we earlier shrunk the dialog to fit in the viewport, reset it to its natural size
                        if(this._singleChild){
                            if(typeof this._singleChildOriginalStyle != "undefined"){
                                this._singleChild.domNode.style.cssText = this._singleChildOriginalStyle;
                                delete this._singleChildOriginalStyle;
                            }
                        }
                        array.forEach([this.domNode, this.containerNode, this.titleBar], function(node){
                            domStyle.set(node, {
                                position: "static",
                                width: "auto",
                                height: "auto"
                            });
                        });
                        this.domNode.style.position = "absolute";
                    }

                    // If necessary, shrink ModelessDialog to fit in viewport and have some space around it
                    // to indicate that it's a popup.  This will also compensate for possible scrollbars on viewport.
                    var viewport = winUtils.getBox(this.ownerDocument), bb, contentDim, centerSize, cb;
                    viewport.w *= this.maxRatio;
                    viewport.h *= this.maxRatio;

                    bb = domGeometry.position(this.domNode);
                    if(bb.w >= viewport.w || bb.h >= viewport.h){
                        dim = {
                            w: Math.min(bb.w, viewport.w),
                            h: Math.min(bb.h, viewport.h)
                        };
                        this._shrunk = true;
                    }else{
                        this._shrunk = false;
                    }
                }

                // Code to run if user has requested an explicit size, or the shrinking code above set an implicit size
                if(dim){
                    // Set this.domNode to specified size
                    domGeometry.setMarginBox(this.domNode, dim);

                    // And then size this.containerNode
                    contentDim = utils.marginBox2contentBox(this.domNode, dim);
                    centerSize = {domNode: this.containerNode, region: "center"};
                    utils.layoutChildren(this.domNode, contentDim,
                        [ {domNode: this.titleBar, region: "top"}, centerSize ]);

                    // And then if this.containerNode has a single layout widget child, size it too.
                    // Otherwise, make this.containerNode show a scrollbar if it's overflowing.
                    if(this._singleChild){
                        cb = utils.marginBox2contentBox(this.containerNode, centerSize);
                        // note: if containerNode has padding singleChildSize will have l and t set,
                        // but don't pass them to resize() or it will doubly-offset the child
                        this._singleChild.resize({w: cb.w, h: cb.h});
                        // TODO: save original size for restoring it on another show()?
                    }else{
                        this.containerNode.style.overflow = "auto";
                        this._layoutChildren();     // send resize() event to all child widgets
                    }
                }else{
                    this._layoutChildren();     // send resize() event to all child widgets
                }

                if(!has("touch") && !dim){
                    // If the user has scrolled the viewport then reposition the ModelessDialog.  But don't do it for touch
                    // devices, because it will counteract when a keyboard pops up and then the browser auto-scrolls
                    // the focused node into view.
                    this._position();
                }
            }
        },

        _layoutChildren: function(){
            // Override _ContentPaneResizeMixin._layoutChildren because even when there's just a single layout child
            // widget, sometimes we don't want to size it explicitly (i.e. to pass a dim argument to resize())

            array.forEach(this.getChildren(), function(widget){
                if(widget.resize){
                    widget.resize();
                }
            });
        },

        destroy: function(){
            if(this._fadeInDeferred){
                this._fadeInDeferred.cancel();
            }
            if(this._fadeOutDeferred){
                this._fadeOutDeferred.cancel();
            }
            if(this._moveable){
                this._moveable.destroy();
            }
            var h = null;
            while(h = this._modalconnects.pop()){
                h.remove();
            }

            DialogLevelManager.hide(this);

            _currentDialog = null;

            this.inherited(arguments);

        }
    });

    if(has("dojo-bidi")){
        _DialogBase = declare("dijit._DialogBase", _DialogBase, {
            _setTitleAttr: function(/*String*/ title){
                this._set("title", title);
                this.titleNode.innerHTML = title;
                this.applyTextDir(this.titleNode);
            },

            _setTextDirAttr: function(textDir){
                if(this._created && this.textDir != textDir){
                    this._set("textDir", textDir);
                    this.set("title", this.title);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    ModelessDialog = declare("beacons.common.ModelessDialog", [ContentPane, _DialogBase], {
        // summary:
        //      A modal dialog Widget.
        // description:
        //      Pops up a modeless dialog window. ModelessDialog is extended from
        //      ContentPane so it supports all the same parameters (href, etc.).
        // example:
        // |    <div data-dojo-type="beacons/common/ModelessDialog" data-dojo-props="href: 'test.html'"></div>
        // example:
        // |    var foo = new ModelessDialog({ title: "test dialog", content: "test content" });
        // |    foo.placeAt(win.body());
        // |    foo.startup();
    });
    ModelessDialog._DialogBase = _DialogBase;   // for monkey patching and dojox/widget/DialogSimple

    DialogLevelManager = ModelessDialog._DialogLevelManager = {
        // summary:
        //      Controls the various active "levels" on the page, starting with the
        //      stuff initially visible on the page (at z-index 0), and then having an entry for
        //      each ModelessDialog shown.

        _beginZIndex: 750,

        show: function(/*dijit/_WidgetBase*/ dialog/*, / *Object* / underlayAttrs*/){
            // summary:
            //      Call right before fade-in animation for new dialog.
            //      Saves current focus, displays/adjusts underlay for new dialog,
            //      and sets the z-index of the dialog itself.
            //
            //      New dialog will be displayed on top of all currently displayed dialogs.
            //
            //      Caller is responsible for setting focus in new dialog after the fade-in
            //      animation completes.

            // Save current focus
            ds[ds.length - 1].focus = focus.curNode;

            // Set z-index a bit above previous dialog
            var zIndex = ds[ds.length - 1].dialog ? ds[ds.length - 1].zIndex + 2 : ModelessDialog._DialogLevelManager._beginZIndex;
            domStyle.set(dialog.domNode, 'zIndex', zIndex);


            ds.push({dialog: dialog, /*underlayAttrs: underlayAttrs, */zIndex: zIndex});
        },

        hide: function(/*dijit/_WidgetBase*/ dialog){
            // summary:
            //      Called when the specified dialog is hidden/destroyed, after the fade-out
            //      animation ends, in order to reset page focus, fix the underlay, etc.
            //      If the specified dialog isn't open then does nothing.
            //
            //      Caller is responsible for either setting display:none on the dialog domNode,
            //      or calling dijit/popup.hide(), or removing it from the page DOM.
            var pd, focus, idx;
            if(ds[ds.length - 1].dialog == dialog){
                // Removing the top (or only) dialog in the stack, return focus
                // to previous dialog

                ds.pop();

                pd = ds[ds.length - 1]; // the new active dialog (or the base page itself)

                // Adjust focus.
                // TODO: regardless of setting of dialog.refocus, if the exeucte() method set focus somewhere,
                // don't shift focus back to button.  Note that execute() runs at the start of the fade-out but
                // this code runs later, at the end of the fade-out.  Menu has code like this.
                if(dialog.refocus){
                    // If we are returning control to a previous dialog but for some reason
                    // that dialog didn't have a focused field, set focus to first focusable item.
                    // This situation could happen if two dialogs appeared at nearly the same time,
                    // since a dialog doesn't set it's focus until the fade-in is finished.
                    focus = pd.focus;
                    if(pd.dialog && (!focus || !dom.isDescendant(focus, pd.dialog.domNode))){
                        pd.dialog._getFocusItems();
                        focus = pd.dialog._firstFocusItem;
                    }

                    if(focus){
                        // Refocus the button that spawned the ModelessDialog.   This will fail in corner cases including
                        // page unload on IE, because the dijit/form/Button that launched the ModelessDialog may get destroyed
                        // before this code runs.  (#15058)
                        try{
                            focus.focus();
                        }catch(e){
                            ;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }else{
                // Removing a dialog out of order (#9944, #10705).
                // Don't need to mess with underlay or z-index or anything.
                idx = array.indexOf(array.map(ds, function(elem){
                    return elem.dialog;
                }), dialog);
                if(idx != -1){
                    ds.splice(idx, 1);
                }
            }
        },

        isTop: function(/*dijit/_WidgetBase*/ dialog){
            // summary:
            //      Returns true if specified ModelessDialog is the top in the task
            return ds[ds.length - 1].dialog == dialog;
        }
    };

    // Stack representing the various active "levels" on the page, starting with the
    // stuff initially visible on the page (at z-index 0), and then having an entry for
    // each ModelessDialog shown.
    // Each element in stack has form {
    //      dialog: dialogWidget,
    //      focus: returnFromGetFocus(),
    //      underlayAttrs: attributes to set on underlay (when this widget is active)
    // }
    ds = ModelessDialog._dialogStack = [
        {dialog: null, focus: null/*, underlayAttrs: null*/}    // entry for stuff at z-index: 0
    ];

    // Back compat w/1.6, remove for 2.0
    if(has("dijit-legacy-requires")){
        ready(0, function(){
            var requires = ["dijit/TooltipDialog"];
            require(requires);  // use indirection so modules not rolled into a build
        });
    }

    ModelessDialog.closeCurrent = function() {
        if(_currentDialog) {
            _currentDialog.destroy();
        }
    };
    return ModelessDialog;
});
```